# trouble positioning buttons and background gradient

Tags: html, button, background

`enter code here`I'm new to html and all things webpagey... but through trial and error i've managed to create a local site with a plug in for a game.. never mind the game or plugin.

i've been having trouble positioning some of the buttons, specifically the "high scores" and "personal best" buttons i tried centering them along with the others but they would overlap them.

does an one have any suggestions?

also i'm trying to add a color gradient to the background, i've tried a few on google but the code format seems to be different.

please keep in mind that everything i've done is just by trial and error, and i know nothing of code design or coding ettiqutte so please excuse me if my code is a little messy and hard to understand.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>ORBIT COLLISION</title>

<p>

<font size="7" face="Georgia, Arial" color="ffff00">
    <center>OSUPER-DUPER-ORBITER-er</center>

</p>

</head>

<body bgcolor=
"00ff00"
>

<FORM 
METHOD="LINK" 
ACTION="index3.html">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" 
VALUE="High Scores"
style="position: absolute; left: 700px; top: 680px; " >
</FORM>

<FORM 
METHOD="LINK" 
ACTION="index4.html">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" 
VALUE="Personal best"
style="position: absolute; left: 500px; top: 680px; " >
</FORM>

</body>

<center>
<EMBED SRC="Broken Promises.mp3" 
HIDDEN="False" 
AUTOSTART="False" 
width="500" height="500">
</center>




<center>
<button type=>Start 
<button type=>Pause  
<button type=>Save
<button type=>Load


</html>
```

Comment: using of font is deprecated.. when you open a tag you should always close it (see the last opened `<center>` tag.. give us an example.. maybe an appropriate jsfiddle